# Wire size to feed a 95 amp pool panel 90' from home

Tags: wiring

I'm installing a 95 amp pool panel 90' from a 200 amp panel inside my house. What wire and breaker size should I feed it with?

Comment: Is the load 95 amps or is the panel I ask because 95 is not a normal panel size. If we know the actual load we can provide the most accurate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What wire size for 100 Amp sub panel 100ft in length form 200 Amp main panel?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/158215/what-wire-size-for-100-amp-sub-panel-100ft-in-length-form-200-amp-main-panel)

Comment: Do your installation instructions give any requirements? Does this number accommodate 125% motor and constant load requirements? Do you need to add capacity for lights and service receptacle? If 95A is inclusive of all derating factors #3 copper would work. If the full 95A is subject to 125% and you need accessory power you could easily need 1/0 copper.

Comment: Where do you live?  Is this going to be 240VAC, three phase, or something else?  In any case, I'd recommend looking up both local code and any online chart of peak&steady-state amperage vs distance vs wire size

Comment: I take it this pool panel will be either freestanding or attached to a poolhouse, not attached to the building it's fed from? Also, is this "pool panel" a prepackaged assembly, or a plain loadcenter?